# Method listDuplicates() error

Tags: c#-3.0

Can somebody help me with this problem here. I'm a newbie . I'm trying to find file duplicates or files with the  same content in a directory and write texfile to display duplicates but now it says input string was not in a correct format

```
   public static List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>(); 
    public static void ListDrive(string drive)
    {
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(drive);
            foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
            {
                files.Add(fi);
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        { }
    }
    //Find duplicates

    public static void ListDuplicates()
    {
        var duplicatedFiles = files.GroupBy(x => new { x.Length }).Where(t => t.Count() > 1).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("Total items: {0}", files.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Probably duplicates {0} ", duplicatedFiles.Count());
        StreamWriter duplicatesFoundLog = new StreamWriter("log.txt");
        foreach (var filter in duplicatedFiles)
        {
            duplicatesFoundLog.WriteLine("Probably duplicated item: Name: { 0}, Length: { 1}",
            filter.Key.Length);
            var items = files.Where(x => x.Length == filter.Key.Length).ToList();
            int c = 1;
            foreach (var suspected in items)
            {
                duplicatesFoundLog.WriteLine("{3},{ 0}- { 1}, Creation date { 2}",
                suspected.Name, suspected.FullName, suspected.CreationTime, c);
                c++;

            }
            duplicatesFoundLog.WriteLine();



        }
        duplicatesFoundLog.Flush();
        duplicatesFoundLog.Close();
    }
```

Here is my client method that invokes the two methods

```
     try
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Enter the path");
            string path = Console.ReadLine();

            ListDrive(path);
            ListDuplicates();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Your help will be high appreciated...

Comment: Post the actual error, and also the `path` value :)

Answer (score 0):

Please eliminate the space, for example change `{ 0}` to `{0}`. If you do this for all locations the error should go away.

If you want spaces, make the code `"{3}, {0}-  {1}, Creation date  {2}"`. i.e. Add the space before the opening `{`, not after. The format items need have no space after the first opening brace to be interpreted as a formatting item correctly.